# In Play 2 framework (Java), how to add User object to session after authentication

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I looked at the ["zentasks" sample code](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/java/zentasks) to learn some basic user login and security stuff.  The Appication controller has an [authenticate method](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/zentasks/app/controllers/Application.java#L41), and during that method the [User.authenticate method](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/zentasks/app/controllers/Application.java#L21) is called.  Here are a couple code snippets from those links:

```
public static Result authenticate() {
    Form<Login> loginForm = form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();
    if(loginForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(login.render(loginForm));
    } else {
        session("email", loginForm.get().email);
        return redirect(
            routes.Projects.index()
        );
    }
}
...
public static class Login {

    public String email;
    public String password;

    public String validate() {
        if(User.authenticate(email, password) == null) {
            return "Invalid user or password";
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

As you can see, if it authenticates (ie, finds a User object), the `authenticate` method adds "email" to the session.  I'd like to add the full user object instead, but in the controller action, where I have the session, I don't have the `User` object.  I don't want to requery the database, I'd like to use the same `User` object that was just found in `Login.validate`.  What's a good way to do that?

Comment: BTW do you really need to add store ie. password in session scope, which is stored in the cookies ? BTW there are more advanced authorization/authentication modules for an example play_authenticate (my fav.) or secure_social, both uses better mechanics than the simplest possible sample from Zentasks

Comment: Thanks, I will check out those modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't simply add a field to your login class?

```
public static class Login {

    public String email;
    public String password;
    public User user;

    public String validate() {
        user = User.authenticate(email, password);
        if(user == null) {
            return "Invalid user or password";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Not that this will necessarily help you, looking at the API it seems you can't add an object to the session, only Strings.

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.4/java/play/mvc/Http.Session.html

Comment: That works. I was confused.  I now see that Play is trying to be stateless, so I should probably drop my servlet habits, like putting a User in the session.